# Detecting CSS browser inconsistent rendering by means of JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css, debugging, firefox, cross-platform

I have a `input[type="text"]` that has padding applied to it and it behaves differently in firefox PC then on a mac.

Can I debug this inconsistency with JavaScript?
Based on the code below, does anyone have any sugestions to resolve my issue?

#### Firefox on Windows (firebug inspection)

```
.searchContainer input {
   border-color:#7C7C7C #C3C3C3 #DDDDDD;
   border-style:solid;
   border-width:1px;
   color:#555555;
   float:left;
   height:12px;
   padding:3px;
  }
```

#### Firefox on Mac(firebug inspection)

```
.searchContainer input  {
   border-color:#7C7C7C #C3C3C3 #DDDDDD;
   border-style:solid;
   border-width:1px;
   color:#555555;
   float:left;
   height:12px;
   padding:3px;
 }
```

No other styles are applied to these inputs.

Any suggestions?

Comment: oops, its the second one!
they are both the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't seem to be setting a `font-size`. When you force a `height` on an input field, you should specify one. It's perfectly conceivable that Macs and PCs have different standard font sizes for input elements.

That said, it's probably better to define the height of the input by setting `padding` and `font-size` but no `height` at all. That way, the browser can handle it easier if the user is using an enlarged font (or the "Text zoom" function in Firefox).

Answer (score 2):

Since you're specifying the input's height in pixels, you'll probably also want to specify the font size in pixels.  It looks like platform-specific font rendering may be the culprit here.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it could be an issue with the font size in the input text box (and maybe the buttons, too). Setting the font size (and even the font family) may solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Check `navigator.platform` in Javascript.

Comment: Ok, i will check out.
Do u have any reason why this happens?

Comment: Thanks, i got to learn a new property of the `navigator` object.